# java -cp [command line] multiple directries

Tags: java, cmd, classpath

I try to execute a class from the command line via java command (Windows cmd). I specified the classpath as well.

```
java -cp bin\ training.TestClient
```

works. But I can't specify another folder with a jar.

```
java -cp bin\:lib\ojdbc7.jar training.TestClient
```

If I try this I get an "main class not found" error.

How can I include the lib\ojdbc7.jar in the classpath as well?

Comment: The classpath separator for Windows is `;` not `:` .

Answer (score 3):

On Windows the path separator is `;`. `:` only works on *nix systems.